# Autohotkey - How to link a GUI to a window to act the same as its parent

Tags: user-interface, window, parent, autohotkey

I would like to link a GUI to a certain window, so it could act like it's a part of it.

This is my GUI and I would like it to follow the Calculator (for testing). If the calculator is minimized, the gui would be minimized as well.

Thanks in advance!

```
#SingleInstance Force
#Persistent

BC = 0

Gui, Color, EEAA99
Gui, Margin , 0, 0
GUI, +AlwaysOnTop -Border -SysMenu -Caption +ToolWindow +Owner
Gui, Font, S48 CDefault Bold CBlue, Verdana
Gui, Add, Text, BackgroundTrans , Units completed:
Gui, Font, S72 CDefault Bold CGreen, Verdana
Gui, Add, Text, BackgroundTrans vBuildCounter, %BC%
WinSet, TransColor, EEAA99
Gui +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow
WinSet, TransColor, EEAA99
Gui -Caption
Gui, Show, % "x" A_ScreenWidth - 400 " y" A_ScreenHeight / 4

:?*:asd:: ;count up
    SoundBeep, 500,500
    BC := BC += 1
    GuiControl,, BuildCounter, %BC%
Return

:?*:qwe:: ;reset the counter
    SoundBeep, 500,500
    BC := 0
    GuiControl,, BuildCounter, %BC%
Return

Esc::
ExitApp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with two scripts. Maybe this can be combined later.

One script is for the ToolMenu, the second for the activation.
Since I could not control the GUI, Show/Hide from the Activation script, I "solved" it by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.Not the most elegant way, but it works...

## ToolMenu.ahk

```
#SingleInstance Force
#installKeybdHook
#Persistent

Gui, Destroy
Gui,+AlwaysOnTop
Gui,+ToolWindow
Gui,+Border
Gui, Add, Button, y5 w60, &LowBeep
Gui, Add, Button, y5 w60, &HighBeep
Gui, Add, Button, y8 h18, X
Gui, Show, y0, MyToolWindow
Return

ButtonLowBeep:
    SoundBeep, 300, 300
Return

ButtonHighBeep:
    SoundBeep, 500, 300
Return

ButtonX:
ButtonCancel:
    Gui, Destroy
ExitApp

^!#F1::
    Gui, Hide
Return

^!#F2::
    Gui, Show, y0, MyToolWindow
Return
```

## DetectWindowChange.ahk

```
#SingleInstance
#installKeybdHook
#Persistent
Global SwitchCounter

Gui +LastFound 
hWnd := WinExist()
DllCall( "RegisterShellHookWindow", UInt,Hwnd )
MsgNum := DllCall( "RegisterWindowMessage", Str,"SHELLHOOK" )
OnMessage( MsgNum, "ShellMessage" )
Return

ShellMessage( wParam )
{
    If (wParam = 4)
    { 
        WinGetTitle, CurrName, A
        If (CurrName = "Calculator" OR CurrName = "MyToolWindow")
        {
            If ( SwitchCounter = 0)
            {
                ;WinRestore, MyToolWindow
                Send, ^!#{F2} ; Send Ctrl+Alt+Win+F2 to trigger GUI Show in GUI script
            }
            SwitchCounter += 1
        }
        Else
        {
            If ( SwitchCounter > 0)
            {
                ;WinMinimize, MyToolWindow
                Send, ^!#{F1} ; Send Ctrl+Alt+Win+F1 to trigger GUI Hide in GUI script
            }
            SwitchCounter := 0
        }
    }
}
Return
```

Let me know how this works...

Comment: Interesting :) It does work, I'm gonna play with it tomorrow. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Please provide some feedback on the proposed solution and if the answer was helpful, then please "Accept" that answer by clicking on the white check-mark to turn it green. Thank you!

Comment: Please "Accept" the given answer by clicking on the WHITE "Check-mark", next to that answer, to turn it GREEN. Thank you! See: [Accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/210367)

Answer (score 1):

You can (as far as I know) only do this with a settimer.

Pseudo code, not tested!

```
SetTitleMatchMode := 2
SetTimer, CheckWindow, 200

CheckWindow:
    If WinActive("Calculator")
    {
       Gui, Show, % "x" A_ScreenWidth - 400 " y" A_ScreenHeight / 4, Popup
    }
    Else If !WinActive("Popup")
    {
        Gui, Hide
    }
Return
```

Edit: Added a condition to avoid hiding the popup if it is activated.

Comment: I'm using AutoHotKey_L. I've also seen something like Set_parent_by_title  but I couldn't make it work. :/

Comment: Just changed the minimize to GUI, Hide or GUI, Show

Comment: The problem is when it runs the GUI show command, it takes away the focus of the calculator and activates the GUI. This hides the GUI, ask Calculator isn't active. Then Calculator becomes active which shows the GUI again... And it's switching between the two windows all the time.